# Empty Checkin Response

Tags: facebook-graph-api, checkin

I'm having an issue that I've seen in a couple of places, but with no real resolution.

I'm attempting to view my friends' checkins using the /checking api.  I'd prefer not to use fql, as proposed in this answer: [Graph Checkin method returns empty data](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7878010/graph-checkin-method-returns-empty-data), because I'd like to have all of the user/place/checkin meta data in one call.

I've tested the call using the access token that all the examples on the Graph API docs site use (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).  When I use that access token on this url:

https://graph.facebook.com/103309013088837/checkins?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

I get back a result with one checkin.

However, when I use the token I've generated via my app on the same url I get an empty data set.  I've confirmed that the permissions on both tokens are the same using the /me/permissions call and that other calls return the same result for both access tokens.

Is there something that needs to be configured on the app side?  Is there anything else I could be doing incorrectly?